# How to make texture visible in unity from blender file

Tags: texturing, game-engine, import, unity

I've imported a tree to Unity that I've made in blender, but the texture of the tree is not visible. Could you please tell me how to make that texture visible?
[image: Tree in unity]

I am a beginer and I don't know how to actualy export it or what to select when exporting in blender. I only saved this 'maple' .blend file to my assets folder and that's it. I thought the tree would show up with the texture, but it didn't and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: This question is right on the border of off topic and on topic. If it focused more on how you exported it in Blender, then it might be off topic. But the fact that it focuses mainly on Unity makes me think it is more off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about more about Unity than it is about Blender.

Comment: I am a beginer and I don't know how to actualy export it or what to select when exporting in blender. I only saved this 'maple' .blend file to my assets folder of unity project and that's it. I thought the tree would show up with the texture, but it didn't and I don't know what to do.